# NHibernate HQL - Joining

Tags: nhibernate, join, hql

I want todo a simple join, well just comparing the ID's in two tables..

I have my Group Table, containing;

- ID
- Name
- etc..

And i have my GroupMap Table containing;

- ID
- GroupID
- ItemID

My query takes a GroupMap.ItemID and is meant to return a list of groups that the itemID belongs to, in SQL I would have done this;

```
select Group.* from Group, GroupMap Where GroupMap.ItemID = '527' and Group.ID = GroupMap.GroupID;
```

This returns what i require, i just cant seem to replicate it in HQL, I thought it would have been quite trivial.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a theta join in hql

```
select g from Group g, GroupMap m Where m.ItemID = '527' and g.ID = m.GroupID
```

Answer (score 3):

With a HQL, you do not think in terms of tables and relations between those tables, but in entities and associations between those entities.

So, if you have the Group and GroupMap classes (which you've mapped to your DB tables), you'll have to write your HQL something like this:

```
from Group as g inner join g.Maps as m where  m.ItemID = '527'
```

That is, supposing your Group entity has a collection of GroupMap entities ...

Comment: Thanks, i'm still trying to get my head around it. The Group entity doesn't contain a collection of GroupMaps. Is there another way of achieving my query?